# Spoonacular Api login/signup page not working properly

Tags: javascript, spoonacular

So for a test project I'm trying to make an account on spoonacular Api website. Now, I've made an account on just the normal side of spoonacular but when I try to login or make an account or anything on spoonacular it doesn't work. Either I get "Request Failed with a 404" or some other error message.

I've searched the internet and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

worked fine for me, I went to spoonacular made an account, got the api out of the console window for my account. and I was able to use it.  see snippet below.

```js
    document.getElementById('fetchRecipes').addEventListener('click', function() {
            const apiKey = 'myapikey'; // Consider securing your API key
            const url = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=apples,+flour,+sugar&number=2&apiKey=${apiKey}`;

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data); // Log the fetched recipes to the console
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
                });
        });
```

```html
 <button id="fetchRecipes">Fetch Recipes</button>
```

Comment: Alright I'll try that.